# React-Native: The subject line of email is same as the message contents using Share.share

Tags: react-native

It's a pretty strange problem I have been facing. I am using Share.share which takes message, subject(ios) and title (for gmail) as an argument. In the android it works fine. i.e. The subject line is "I am the title" whereas the message body is "I am groot". But in iOS, the subject line is always same as the message, like the screenshot shown below:[image: Subject line same as the message body] Any help would be highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

```
onShare = async () => {
    try {
      await Share.share(
        {
          message: "I am groot",
          title: "I am the title",
        },
        {
          subject: "I am the subject line",
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      ...
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of importing Share from react-native, when I imported it from react-native-share, it fixed my problem.

Comment: I have the same problem but I'm already importing from react-native-share... react-native-share 7.1.2 and Share.open() method

Comment: Cant' be done in expo?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/share), `Share` title property is used only as a title for the message. To set the email subject you need to set the `subject` property in the options object (note: this only works on IOS)

Comment: Worth noting `subject` goes into the second parameter, not the first. `Share.share(content, options);`